# La différence entre « agissement » et « action », et d'autres cas similaires

Tags: noms, suffixes

En français, il y a plusieurs moyens de façonner un verbe pour qu’il devienne un substantif. On connait par exemple :

- agissement,   action
- fléchissement, flexion

Malgré la longueur des mots à gauche, je les utilise plus souvent parce qu’ils sont jolis. Pour certains mots, comme *garnissement* et *garnison*, c’est flagrant que leurs sens ne sont point les mêmes. Pour beaucoup d’autre choses par contre, c’est flou.

Alors, je ne sais pas s’il y a toujours une différence entre ce que ces deux mots veulent dire.
 Moi-même je dirais que le premier fléchissement est lié à *ce que l’on fait*, alors que le deuxième fait plutôt apparaître *comment* on le met en œuvre. J'espère que vous pouvez me donner une règle générale, pourvu qu'elle existe.

Est-il possible de clarifier comment l’emploi de ces terminaisons marche ?

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de réponse générale. La seule solution est certainement le dictionnaire pour chaque cas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La dérivation multiple (on pourrait ajouter *garniture*) via des suffixes (ou des emprunt de termes apparentés depuis d'autres langues) dont le sens est relativement flou est un élément très communs des langues indo-européennes, et deux verbes donnés ne forment pas nécessairement leurs dérivés avec les mêmes suffixes. Comme le note Evpok, la seule référence est le dictionnaire puisque dans la vaste majorité des cas, il  s'agit plus ou moins d'accidents historiques (par exemple quand la dérivation vient directement du latin, comme c'est le cas de *flexion*).

Comment: Je vous remercie pour vos réponses

Answer (score 0):

Je n'ai pas de règle générale ni d'explications historiques à proposer mais concernant le premier exemple il y a une grande différence de sens. Je pense qu'on peut parfois dire “fléchissement” pour “flexion” mais certainement pas “agissement” pour “action”.

Pour autant que je sache, “agissement” n'existe plus de nos jours qu'au pluriel, avec un sens fortement péjoratif comme dans cet exemple pris parmi les premiers résultats de Google actualité: « Rouen : les agissements d'un gang de voleurs de voitures stoppés ».

Du coup, je pense que le mot est un peu délicat à employer si vous n'êtes pas tout-à-fait sûr de votre français et j'éviterais certainement de l'utiliser fréquemment.